# How to render propeties with nonzero values inside template strings

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am actually trying to render an `HTMLElement` using template strings. The function goes like this

```
function renderContent(){
  return `<div class="card">
              <span>Content goes here</span>
              <ul class="list">
                 ${renderList()}
              </ul>
          </div>`
}
```

And the `renderList()` function goes like this

```
function renderList() {
  const valueWithCount = { a : 1, b: 0, c:0, d:1}
  return Object.entries(valueWithCount).map(([key, value]) => {
    return `<li>
                    <span class="key">${key}:</span>
                    <span class="value">${value}</span>
            </li>`;
  });
}
```

I want the content to be rendered as

```
Content goes here
a:1
d:1
```

I dont want to render the the properties with value 0.I could write `value && (some HTML content)`. But since its inside the template string, even 0 gets printed. If I go with ternary `value ? some content : null` , the behavior is same.The same case with undefined as well.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.filter()` instead of `.map()`:

```
function renderList() {
  const valueWithCount = { a : 1, b: 0, c:0, d:1}
  return Object.entries(valueWithCount).filter(([key, value]) => {
    if(value !== 0)
    return `<li>
                    <span class="key">${key}:</span>
                    <span class="value">${value}</span>
            </li>`;
   return null;
  });
}
```

`return null` in other cases.